# openstack swift. region affinity account

Tags: openstack, openstack-swift, s3cmd

Is it possible with openstack swift?

I have cluster with 6 nodes in 3 datacenters(regions). In one datacenter I have huge disks. I want store my backups only in this region, but all other data should be available across regions.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

I think the best way to do it is to create a storage policy, limiting  your options and apply this policy to your container.

You can find more info here: http://docs.openstack.org/developer/swift/overview_policies.html